Tkinter scrollbar on treeview table disappears when resized
I wrote a table class using Treeview:
class SimpleDataTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, colHeadings, colWidths, height):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.colHeadings = colHeadings
        self.colWidths = colWidths
        self.height = height
        self.dataDict = {}

        self.tree = None
        self.vsb = None
        self.hsb = None

        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=self.colHeadings, show="headings", height=self.height)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')

        self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')

        self.hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hsb.set)
        self.hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

        for i in range(2):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.setupColumns()
        self.populateData()

        # TODO: motion binding callbacks when the user resizes row/column
        #  self.tree.bind("<Configure>", self.onTreeviewConfigure) --> this doesn't work
        # TODO: A way to delete data [and delete from the report]

    def addData(self, key, values: List[Any]):
        self.dataDict[key] = self.processValuesForDisplay(values)
        self.updateData()

    def setupColumns(self):
        for i,col in enumerate(self.colHeadings):
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.CENTER)
            self.tree.column(col, width=self.colWidths[i], anchor=tk.CENTER)
    
    def processValuesForDisplay(self, values: List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
        for i,val in enumerate(values):
            if isinstance(val, float):
                values[i] = round(val, 2)
        return values

    def populateData(self):
        for key, values in self.dataDict.items():
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=tuple(values), text=str(key))

    def updateData(self):
        # When new data is added, the whole table gets re-wriiten. Works with simple cases with a few rows and cols
        # Clear the existing data, self.tree.get_children() returns a tuple which we'd need to unpacks
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children()) 
        self.populateData()
    
    def selectRowByKey(self, key):
        for item in self.tree.get_children():
            if self.tree.item(item, 'text') == str(key):
                self.tree.selection_set(item)
                self.tree.focus(item)
                self.tree.tag_configure('selected', background='lightblue')  # Change the background color to light blue
                self.tree.item(item, tags=('selected',))
                break

    def onTreeviewConfigure(self, event):
        # Resize columns when the treeview is configured (e.g., on window resize)
        for i, col in enumerate(self.colHeadings):
            width = self.tree.column(col, option="width")
            self.colWidths[i] = width
        self.resizeColumns()

    def resizeColumns(self):
        # Resize the columns based on stored widths
        for i, col in enumerate(self.colHeadings):
            width = self.colWidths[i]
            print(width)
            self.tree.column(col, width=width, anchor=tk.CENTER)

I put this table in a frame via below code:
self.dataTable = SimpleDataTable(self, colHeadings = table_titles, colWidths = [350] * len(table_titles)  ,height = 3)
        self.dataTable.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=12, pady=10, padx=(20, 10))

Initially, the table has an expected look. The number of columns are dynamic. If the columns exceed the frame size, the scrollbar activates, and I can use that to see all the columns.
Now, if the use wants to resize any single column, the scrollbar disappears and all the columns shrink within the parent frame size.
I have tried different types of callbacks (shown in code) so the table is redrawn when an event occurs, but nothing is happening. What can I do?
I want the user to adjust column widths and the scrollbar to still remain active.
Note that, all the grids are configured in the relevant frames.

I had to add stretch=0 when setting width:
self.tree.column(col, width=self.colWidths[i], anchor=tk.CENTER, stretch=0)
